# Given Access Token, how can I get domain / name of Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using the Windows Azure Management Libraries and is getting a list of subscriptions and the WAAD tenant id (a guid) for each subscription. This means I just need to sign in to the WAAD to get permision to manage my subscriptions.

I am developing an application and guids are not that pritty in the UI so I am looking for some C# code or just just the rest call I can query for the name.

I have a access token from the AuthenticatinoContext of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayName property should give you what you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974467.aspx

This is available via a REST call to the Graph API. For more information on the Graph, see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx