# How can I programmatically retrieve the domain name of the Azure Active Directory in a given subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm working on an application that will allow users to authenticate to Azure Active Directory and then manage resources in their Azure account via Azure Resource Manager API calls.

I've found several walkthroughs on building such an app including this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-api-authentication/).  However, in the part that discusses authentication with Azure Active Directory, there's a step showing the need to manually retrieve the Azure Active Directory name from the Azure Portal.

The directory name is plugged into app settings (and ultimately authentication calls to the directory) as follows

> http://login.microsoftonline.com/{directory_domain_name}/OAuth2/Authorize

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve {directory_domain_name} without requiring users to login and lookup the information in the Azure Portal?

The one answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144208/given-access-token-how-can-i-get-domain-name-of-windows-azure-active-director) has a dead link and another pointing to the Graph API, which seems to still require the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular scenario, look like you want to build an app that will be users from different Azure AD tenants. This scenario is best addressed by building a multi-tenant application.

To make your application multi-tenant, you'll need to go to the Azure Portal and in the Configure tab of your Azure AD application, set the "Application is Mult-Tenant" option to yes.

Once you do this, you can just call

```
http://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth/authorize
http://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth/token
```

And Azure AD will resolve the figure out which tenant to authenticate against based on the the credential that the user types in.

More information on multi-tenant applications:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-multitenant-identity-authenticate/

Sample multi-tenant application: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect

Comment: To be clear this is an app that will be distributed so that users may install into their own Azure account as they please.  In other words, there's no centralized version of the app anywhere.  Just the same, the multi-tenant option may still work.

If I enable multi-tenant authentication, does that affect the authorization side at all?  A user from another directory would still have to be granted some sort of Azure role in the directory in which the app is installed in order to manage assets there, correct?

Comment: In order for any app to integrate with Azure AD, it needs to be registered somewhere. Where did you register it? If it was apps.dev.microsoft.com then it's registered in a default tenant and setup as multi-tenant as default. If it was registered in the Azure portal, it'll be part of whatever Azure AD tenant you registered it in.

Comment: As for it affecting authorization, nothing outside of requiring that you use /common instead of /domainName.

Comment: To your last question, yes, the user will still need to have an Azure subscription and be assigned a role that gives them permission to whatever you want to do on their behalf.

Comment: The app is deployed via a Powershell script and ARM template. Within that script there's a call to New-AzureRmADApplication.  The ideal scenario I was looking for was a Powershell method to retrieve the directory name, which would then get passed as a parameter to the ARM template and ultimately the app settings.